Error: ARM register expected -- `mov x0,0' but aarch64
I've just got my pi 4B and i'm trying to compile some inline assembly and i'm getting an error from gcc:
Error: ARM register expected -- `mov x0,0'

which, after some googling, indicates that my gcc and my OS is 32bit.  i'm using an SD card with a pre-installed raspbian, so i'm not 100% sure what i'm testing on but uname appears to say it's 64bit:
$ uname -mrs
Linux 6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8 aarch64
$ lscpu |head -1
Architecture:                       aarch64
$ head -2 /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"

my gcc appears to report it's 32bit:
$ gcc -v 2>&1 |grep Targ
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf

i got clang-13 and it reports a similar message:
$ clang t.c
t.c:2:11: error: operand must be a register in range [r0, r15]
<snip>
$ clang -v 2>&1  |head -2
Raspbian clang version 13.0.1-11+rpi1+b1
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf

my test code is
$ cat t.c
int main() {
 __asm__ ("mov x0,0;");
 return 1;
}
$ gcc t.c
/tmp/ccjuI3GY.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccjuI3GY.s:28: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov x0,0'

why would my OS be 64bit, but two installed compilers be 32bit?

Which Pi? What OS is installed (detail including version)? It is unclear what you are asking or what you have done. Raspbian is a 32 bit OS.

@Milliways - it's a pi 4B. "Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)" so it's 32bit? is there a command that would confirm this?

If it claims to be Raspbian it is 32 bit. It is using a 64 bit kernel (certainly not up to date) If you want 64 bit (which I recommend) install Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit which identifies as Debian. There are many ways to confirm this but I don't currently have access to a Pi.

@Milliways so I blew away what i had and used rpi-imager to get 64bit OS and that has fixed my problem.  maybe apt-config dump |grep Arch would have confirmed the 32bit question -- i don't know, it's gone now. my problem is gone, too. thanks for your suggestion
